# I want to use http://xxxxxx/{id} and http://xxxxxx/{md5} together

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use http://xxxxxx/{id} and http://xxxxxx/{md5}

I think it work like this

```
class ItemViewSEt(viewsets.ModelVieSet):
    queryset = item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    lookup_field = 'id'

    @detail_route(methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[AllowAny])
    def test(self, request):
        self.lookup_field = 'md5'
```

but it doesn't work with following error

check() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

how can i solve that problem?

Do I seperate viewset? or make method view and include url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think changing `lookup_field` in the method will work.
However, you can query using the md5 and return response from the method.

By default, the `detail_route` adds `pk` as parameter that you can re-use.

So the sample code would be

```
@detail_route(methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[AllowAny])
    def test(self, request, pk=None):
        obj = Item.objects.get(md5=pk)
        ser = ItemSerializer(obj)
        return Response(ser.data)
```

Comment: Does this make an ambiguity in `URLDispatcher` ?

Comment: More specifically, How could distinguish between `/test/123/` and `/test/d926d7bb9ccf46fc04a61bd65d87b9b3/` ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge url regex should be able to do that

Comment: `\w+` will match all integers too, right? So,can you show some examples?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge, I do not have example, but you can order defining these urls and their regex to achieve what OP wants.